# How do we name the "spring-mounted spikes" component on MacBook Pro motherboards?

Tags: identification, motherboard

**How to we name these components** that we see on the motherboards of the MacBook Pro (either silvered or gold) when the bottom cover lid is removed, and that seem mounted on springs?

Ancillary, does someone know if their purpose to detect the opening of the cover lid, or to ensure some contact with the mass? 
(N.B. The MacBook is still working when the lid has been removed.)

[image: Small bulbs mounted on springs on MacBook Pro motherboard]

Comment: Looks like a pogo pin.

Comment: … or "the artist formerly known as spring-loaded contact", @SolveEtCoagula07

Answer (score 4):

Generically, spring-loaded contacts or pogo pins. [Mill-max](https://www.mill-max.com/new_products/detail/103) is one US-based supplier.

[image]

Their primary purpose is probably electrical shielding to reduce EMI and for EMC purposes.  They probably contact a conductive paint or internal metal surface inside the housing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was great help for me ! Regards.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Pogo is a registered trademark of Everett Charles Technologies (ECT). ECT and its subsidiaries have been manufacturing Pogo pins for over forty years.  (ref [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_pin))

They are used for test Fixtures and EMI ground contacts in this application.

Comment: Yes, they (ECT) were (and maybe still are) the kings of spring-loaded test pins.  I used to design bed-of-nails ICT fixtures for like 13 years at HP.

Comment: Yes we had over 5k "Bed-of-Nails" to support all the products in Winnipeg we once acquired from plant closures in Nogales, Guadalajara, Bristol, Singapore, etc for all peripheral products at Unisys. I was TE Mgr at the time with over 30 mainframes for testing , 3 clean rooms for servo-writers and HDA assy, plus PCB test which was like a Smithsonian of antique ICT,FCT testers ( dozen or so)

Comment: Nice. I got goose-bumps now thinking about those good-old-days. Let's not forget about wire-wrap technology too;-)

Comment: i remember a WW test fixture supplied by a major aerospace company that designed jet controller motherboards that looked like NYC on google earth, which had some interesting inductance issues on their fixture design. I modified one part to reduce the pogo length and use twisted pair AWG 30 WW. I was Eng Mgr at C-MAC a now defunct CM in WInnipeg and my TE could not fix the measurement problems.

Comment: Wire wrap is still alive and kicking, however, ECT went out of the test fixture business.

Comment: Not so, they just split the biz in 2 https://xcerra.com/ectinfo   ect https://ect-fsg.com/welcome

Comment: Thank you very much, before your answer I had been desesperately searching the name of this component.